# Linux support for AMP architecture?

Tags: linux, smp

When I search about linux kernel, I know that linux support for SMP architecture.
But I don't find any specification about the linux for AMP.
Does linux support for AMP?
Have any documents or specification for descripting about that?

Anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Linux has the remoteproc subsystem and the closely tied virtio and rpmsg. remoteproc can be use to boot up a firmware blob on the remote core and the communicated with it using rpmsg. Examples of such processors include iMX7 and Vybrid. Vybrid has a Cortex A5 and Cortex M4.

See the documentation on [remoteproc](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/remoteproc.txt). ARM's [big.Little](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_big.LITTLE) might also interest you.

Comment: I'm sorry, But I don't understand your answer.
remoteproc subsystem can config for both AMP and SMP?
Could you explain more detail?

Comment: No remoteproc won't configure for SMP or AMP. It basically takes a firmware blob and sets up the remote processor so that the remote processor can boot it. Once the remote processor has booted the firmware, it is possible to for Linux and remote processor to communicate by rpmsg which are kind of shared memory channels. So you might send commands to the remote processor or data from Linux side and vice versa .  May be [this](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU-ICSS_Remoteproc_and_RPMsg) makes it more clear.

Answer (score -3):

Yes. AMP precedes SMP, and both techs precede Linux.

Asymmetric multi processing was used when 2 Pentium II 33MhZ processors ran in parallel on the same motherboard.

It's an old Operating System, that is still supported in the current Linux kernel, and is in fact getting a face lift since cloud computing (which is essentially the same concept as AMP, but across a network instead of across a motherboard.

There's no recent talks about AMP around Linux devs, but just ask some of the cloud devs they'll talk your ears off about AMP.